# Write a regex to find sentence inside the parentheses

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I have to use regex inside C# program.
Input string:

WITH Sum_OrderQuantity_CTE
AS (**SELECT ProductKey, EnglishMonthName, SUM(OrderQuantity) AS TotalOrdersByMonth FROM [dbo].[FactInternetSales] fs INNER JOIN [dbo].[DimDate] dd ON dd.DateKey = fs.OrderDateKey GROUP BY ProductKey, EnglishMonthName** ) SELECT ProductKey, AVG(TotalOrdersByMonth) AS 'Average Total Orders By Month' FROM Sum_OrderQuantity_CTE GROUP BY ProductKey ORDER BY ProductKey

I want to find strings which come after AS and is present in the parentheses. There can be multiple AS in the string. I want to find all those sentence present in the parentheses and come after AS.

I have tried some regex but failed to find correct matches:

`AS\s{1,}\((.*?)\)\s{1,}(?=SELECT|UPDATE |INSERT|DELETE|AS\s{1,}\()`
`AS \((.*)\)`
`(?=AS\s{1,}\((.*)\))`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You need a balance group.   Your input has two selects which doesn't give right rusults without a balance grouping.   See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#balancing-group-definitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex is the one you're looking for:

```
(?<=AS \()([^\(\)]*(\([^\(\)]*\))?[^\(\)]*)*(?=\))
```

Link: https://regex101.com/r/m9jLcs/1

Comment: I am getting timeout issue with this regex with the input when there are sub-queries as well. [Link](https://regex101.com/r/8hca4L/1) @Cristiano

Comment: It should return 1 match in [Link](https://regex101.com/r/8hca4L/1) and match: **( Select c.*, t.CustomerId as [cust1] from dbo.CustomerATeam c Join (Select * from dbo.CustomerATeam where CustomerId in (select CustomerId from CustomerATeam)) t on c.CustomerId = t.CustomerId )**